# Excel VBA - shifting of cells

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Looks like a simple shifting of cells, but when there are over 10,000 rows, its too tedious to do manually. Need a quicker way to do this.

INPUT

```
Column A   Column B
1          X
2          Y
1          Z
```

OUTPUT

```
Column A   Column B   Column C
1          X          Z
2          Y
```

Comment: try using screen-prints for the input and output - makes it loads easier for us to understand

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
Sub ShiftCells()

Dim rnAll As Range, rnCell As Range, rnTarget As Range

Set rnAll = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count)

For Each rnCell In rnAll
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range(rnCell.Address, rnAll.Cells(1)), rnCell.Value) > 1 Then
        Set rnTarget = rnAll.Find(rnCell.Value, rnAll.Cells(rnAll.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, True, True)
        rnTarget.EntireRow.Cells(1, Sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = rnCell.Offset(0, 1).Value 'Move value to next free column in corresponding index row
        rnCell.Value = ""
    End If
Next

If rnAll.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count > 0 Then
    rnAll.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End If

End Sub
```

It checks all values in column 1 and if that "key" already exists above it, takes the value from column 2 and puts it into the next available column next to the existing key. It then deletes the empty rows so you end up with 1 unique set of keys on the left with all corresponding values to the right.

---

EDIT - This code moves values from Column B to Columns starting at K, adding the indexes if they dont exist:

```
Sub ShiftCells()

Dim rnAll As Range, rnCell As Range, rnTarget As Range, rnDestination As Range

Set rnAll = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
Set rnDestination = Sheet1.Range("K1:K" & Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count)

For Each rnCell In rnAll
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rnDestination, rnCell.Value) = 0 Then 'Index doesn't exist
        Set rnTarget = rnDestination.Cells(1).Offset(WorksheetFunction.CountA(rnDestination), 0)
            rnTarget.Value = rnCell.Value 'Populate the index if it doesn't exist
            rnTarget.Next.Value = rnCell.Next.Value
    Else 'Index exists
        Set rnTarget = rnDestination.Find(rnCell.Value, rnDestination.Cells(rnAll.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, True, True)
            rnTarget.EntireRow.Cells(1, Sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Next.Value = rnCell.Next.Value 'Move value to next free column if index exists
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Actually, I don't just have data in column B. The data to be shifted is from column B to K. How do I make the necessary adjustment to the coding?

Comment: Edited - is that what you need?